# Linear Transformation eigenvalues: from $\mathbb R^3$ to a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, plane-geometry

Can you guys please help me with this question:
Determine the eigenvalues of the linear transformation.
$P: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ given by projection onto the plane $3x-y-2z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Linear transformation is a projection $P$ then eigenvalues can be only $0$ and $1$ ($P^2=P$).
Because it is projection into two-dimensional subspace (the plane) so there is one zero eigenvalue and two eigenvalues $=1$.

As you see what is important in this case is only that it is a projection onto a plane, specific equation of the plane is not so important for eigenvalues - it is however important for eigenvectors.

Notice  that for eigenvalue  $= 1$ and its  eigenvector $v \ \ $ we have equation $Pv=v$ what means that for this eigenvalue the eigenvector is unchanged by the projection, this is a case for vectors lying in the plane.